# Mutate under multiple conditions with dplyr (NA and grep)

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to change the values in my data (`dat`) using `dplyr`.

Here, the values of `First.name` should be changed.

This should be done under the following conditions: If the values in Company have NA and if the values of Email have a certain string pattern I want to impute the Value "DELETE" otherwise the original values of the First.name should remain.

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>% 
    mutate(First.name = ifelse(
        is.na(Company) == T & 
            ifelse(
                grepl("web|google|gmail|gmx|hotmail|yahoo|t-online|freenet|aol|netscape|kabelmail|onlinehome|outlook", Email), 
                "DELETE", 
                First.name
            )
    ))
```

But I get this Error:

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : Evaluation error: operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types.
```

Comment: I think you need to club the conditions together i.e. `ifelse(is.na(Company) & grepl("web|google|gmail|gmx|hotmail|yahoo|t-online|freenet|aol|netscape|kabelmail|onlinehome|outlook" Email), "DELETE", Email))`,`

Comment: If that doesn't solve it, the problem is likely in your data. Can you share a [mcve] of your data using `dput`?